# Exception propagation in CompletableFuture (java)

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

How can I propagate exception encountered in the following code inside `CompletableFuture.runAsync` to my main thread? I want to catch the `IllegalStateException` in my main thread.

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        // some business logic which needs to run indefinitely
}).exceptionally(ex -> {
    // ex.printStackTrace();
    throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to process", ex);
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot just catch the `ExecutionException` and use `getCause()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a `Collection` of `Throwable` objects and when the `CompletableFuture` completes you can add the exception to the Collection (if it's not null). Then on your main thread you could poll that Collection.

```java
        Set<Throwable> exception = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {

        }).whenComplete((method, e) -> exception.add(e));
```

Another option is to use `whenComplete` with `ExecutorService`. This may not work if you're not using an ExecutorService. The idea is that `whenComplete` will return on the `mainThread` ExecutorService.

```java
        ExecutorService mainThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {

        }).whenCompleteAsync((method, throwable) -> {
            // throw or handle in some way on main thread
        }, mainThread);
```